# python reduce code with replace same name

Tags: python, string, replace

is there a possibility to reduce this code?

```
    Nomefilm = selected_channel[1]
    Nomefilm = Nomefilm.replace('.','').replace('-','').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace('[HD]','').replace('2013','').replace('2014','').replace('2015','').replace('2016','')
    Nomefilm = Nomefilm.replace('PrimaVisione 1','').replace('PrimaVisione 2','').replace('PrimaVisione 3','').replace('PrimaVisione 4','').replace('PrimaVisione 5','').replace('PrimaVisione 6','').replace('PrimaVisione 7','')
    Nomefilm = Nomefilm.replace('PrimaVisione 8','').replace('PrimaVisione 9','').replace('PrimaVisione 10','').replace('PrimaVisione 11','').replace('PrimaVisione 12','').replace('PrimaVisione 13','').replace('PrimaVisione 14','')
    Nomefilm = Nomefilm.replace('PrimaVisione 15','').replace('PrimaVisione 16','').replace('PrimaVisione 17','').replace('PrimaVisione 18','').replace('PrimaVisione 19','').replace('PrimaVisione 20','').replace('PrimaVisione 21','')
    Nomefilm = Nomefilm.replace('Primafila 1-2','').replace('Primafila 3-4','').replace('Primafila 5-6','').replace('Primafila 7-8','').replace('Primafila 9-10','').replace('Primafila 11-12','').replace('Primafila 13-14','').replace('Primafila 15','')
    Nomefilm = Nomefilm.replace('Primafila 16-17','').replace('Primafila 18','').replace('Primafila 19','')
```

Comment: show the initial `Nomefilm` value and the expected result

Comment: Regex would be a good start.

Comment: you can use `regex`  here `re.sub`

Comment: After you perform `replace('-','')`, there will be no `'Primafila 1-2'` anymore.

Comment: is possible have example: replace('PrimaVisione * ',''")
??

Comment: Yes, as @cricket_007 has already suggested you can use regex for that kind of thing. But vanilla `str.replace` doesn't take patterns.

Comment: @Silvio you would delete everything that comes behind it if that'd work

Comment: @silvio Yes, use regular expressions `re.sub`, see my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

Write a function to erase any list of target strings.

```
def erase( s, target):
    for t in target:
        s = s.replace( t, '')
    return s
```

and then

```
TO_ERASE = ( '.', '-', ',' , '(', ')', '[HD]', '2013', 
    ... 
    'Primafila 19',
)


Nomefilm = erase( Nomefilm, TO_ERASE)
```

You might also make use of regular expressions (Python `re` module). For example, you could delete all strings starting with `"Primafila "` and ending with a quantity of digits and hyphens using

```
s = re.sub( 'Primafila\ [0-9\-]+', '', s)
```

Note that this is not exactly the same as your code: it will happily turn `"Primafila 2345-------g"` into `"g"`. It may also require you to learn the syntax of regular expressions, which is effectively a different language (one rather more cryptic than Python). But if the number of similar strings gets too large to sensibly supply as a list, tackling it as a single expression may be the better approach.

Regular expressions can be quite powerful.  A regular expression that matches `"Primofila "` followed by a one- or two-digit number and then optionally by a single hyphen and another one- or two- digit number would be `'Primofila\ [0-9]{1,2}(-[0-9]{1,2})?'`